# Silverlight/WP7: I want to place an Button after the Listbox element which are data bound

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am fairly new to silverlight. I am developing on the windows phone platform.
I want to place a button at the end of the listbox entries which will be bound to data from the webservice (I am using a listbox template)

- List item 1
- List item 2
- List item 3
- List item 4
- List item 5
- List item 6
- List item 7
- List item 8
- ..Button..

I tried number of things of using grid/stackpanel etc to host the button and all my solutions place the button at the bottom of my screen instead of bottom of all the  listbox entries which might span multiple screens.

XAML file I have is below. I want to add a button below the "LBoxItems"

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid  x:Name="ads" >
        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Margin="24,24,0,12"
                x:Name="SearchTitle">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                       FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"
                       Text="{Binding Location}" />
            <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"
                       Text=" > " />
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                       FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"
                       Text="{Binding Category}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"
                   Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource SearchHistoryItemSubTitleConverter}}" />
        </StackPanel>   

    </Grid>
    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->

    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid"
          Grid.Row="2">            
            <ListBox x:Name="LBoxItems"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Margin="24, 0"
                 SelectionChanged="LBoxItems_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <StackPanel Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" >
                            <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"                                        
                                   Text="{Binding Title.Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="-4,20,0,0">
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PublishDate, Converter={StaticResource ItemPublishDateConverter}}" />

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>             
    </Grid>

    <l:SpinnerControl x:Name="SpinnerControl"
                      Width="55"
                      Height="55"
                      Grid.RowSpan="2" />

    <TextBlock x:Name="TxtNoResultsMessage"
               FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"
               Text="No results found"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               Grid.RowSpan="2"
               Visibility="Collapsed" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [ScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.aspx):

```
<ScrollViewer>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="800"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ListBox Grid.Row="0">

            </ListBox>

            <Button Grid.Row="1" Height="30" Content="Test"></Button>
        </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Simply divide the **Grid** inside into two rows, the second one being for the **Button**.

For your specific case it would be:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentGrid"
          Grid.Row="2">    
        <ScrollViewer>
          <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="600"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ListBox x:Name="LBoxItems"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Margin="24, 0"
                 SelectionChanged="LBoxItems_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="0">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <StackPanel Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" >
                            <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"                                        
                                   Text="{Binding Title.Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="-4,20,0,0">
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PublishDate, Converter={StaticResource ItemPublishDateConverter}}" />

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox> 
            <Button Content="Sample" Height="30" Grid.Row="1" />
          </Grid>     
        </ScrollViewer>       
    </Grid>
```

Of course, you can set the appropriate height depending on your situation.

Comment: Thanks Dennis for the reply. If I try to add scrollviewer then my listbox items stops scrolling i.e. i cannot scroll beyond what can be seen on the screen. I have edited my original post to include the xaml I am using. Can u suggest from the xaml where to add the scroll viewer ? thanks again for the reply.

Comment: thanks once again Dennis for the quick reply. however if I do not know the height i.e. if the since it is data bound, it can vary from one entry to 100s of entries. It looks like the button will always appear below the height specified. so it does not automatically appear immediately after the listbox.

Comment: Set the height to Auto then (instead of a fixed value).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do, really is to mix and match different items in the DataTemplate.  If you're not really happy with how the other solutions work out I might consider adding a button to the datatemplate, but set its visibility to collapsed. Then for the very last entry, set its visibility to visible.

Either way you are in for a bit of a hack, but this way the button is in your list box.  If all the button events point to the same handler, and only one is visible, you should be good to go.

Comment: I like this approach better since it is simpler and keeps the button in the list box. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried using the ScrollViewer approach, however I couldn't get rid of the 'stuck scrolling' issue until I disabled the vertical scrollbar on the listbox. Maybe this will help others too.

Comment: Thanks, been trying to figure why that was happening.